# Using vba to combine two queries in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two combo boxes, Combo_A sets the query string in Combo_B. After selecting a choice from combo_B and hitting the go button, one of two queries is executed based on the selection in Combo_A. If choice 1 is selected in Combo_A then the go button executes query A and if choice 2 is selected in Combo_A then the go button executes query B.  This is all working great and it runs by assigning the query name to a variable and then executing with a DoCmd.OpenQuery_Click.

My problem is that i want to take this one step further. I would like to cross reference the results from above with another query when a check box is selected, when not selected it needs to behave exactly the same as i currently have it designed. I know i can create the query but am less comfortable wokring with vba. Can i use the variable name that represend a query to join with another query? here is my vba code so far.

```
Option Compare Database



Private Sub AgencyorCarrierSelection_AfterUpdate()
If AgencyorCarrierSelection = "By Insurance Carrier" Then
    Combo7.Visible = True
    Text13.Value = "Select of of the following Carriers:"
    Text13.Visible = True
    Combo7.RowSource = "SELECT [tblRefInsuranceCarriers].[InsuranceCarrierID], [tblRefInsuranceCarriers].[CarrierName] FROM [tblRefInsuranceCarriers] ORDER BY [CarrierName];"
Else
    Combo7.Visible = True
    Text13.Value = "Select of of the following Agencies:"
    Text13.Visible = True
    Combo7.RowSource = "SELECT [tblRefInsuranceAgencies].[InsuranceAgencyID], [tblRefInsuranceAgencies].[AgencyName] FROM [tblRefInsuranceAgencies] ORDER BY [AgencyName]"
End If
End Sub
Private Sub lblSwitchboard_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "switchboard", acNormal
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmInsuranceInformationConnect"
End Sub
Private Sub RunAgencyorCarrierQuery_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_RunAgencyorCarrierQuery_Click

Dim stDocName As String
If AgencyorCarrierSelection = "By Insurance Carrier" Then
    stDocName = "qryInsuranceCarrierAgentPremiumBreakout_Carrier"
Else
    stDocName = "qryInsuranceCarrierAgentPremiumBreakout_Agency"
End If

DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

Exit_RunAgencyorCarrierQuery_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_RunAgencyorCarrierQuery_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_RunAgencyorCarrierQuery_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: I have read that a few times and still am not sure what you want to do. From what I gather it seems you want to run a third query and I cannot see why you should not just run it as your previous queries.

Comment: What do you mean by "cross-reference"?

Comment: Remou you are correct. I want to run a third query using either 'qryInsuranceCarrierAgentPremiumBreakout_Agency' or 'qryInsuranceCarrierAgentPremiumBreakout_Carrier' as one of the joined queries. What this will retrieve is a list all properties that have the selected insurance carrier/agencie and do not have auto sprinklers (from qryAutoSprinkler). I am currently thinking that i am going to create two new queries and use a nested if statement to solve the problem. Smandoli i believe this answers your question too. Thanks for the input

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

So you will use basically the same query (either A or B), but checking the box will limit results by one extra criterion.  The challenge is the criterion requires another table joined in.

Simplest is to make C and D queries that match A and B, but have the extra table; then `if...then` to the desired query, just as you are already doing.

Or you could make the A and B queries include the joined table so the extra criterion is available, and use a [parameter query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa160564%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to specify whether that criterion is used.  That seems complicated.